# Whats the difference between 0> and > redirections?

Tags: command-line, bash, c, redirect

I cant  redirect the output  of  a particular program  using >  , but it works if i use  0> ,  e.g

```
./foo >  ouput.txt
./foo 0> output.txt
```

this program  writes to the standard using the C function

```
write(0,other_args ... )
```

I  thought the two were equivalent, since the standard output descriptor is 0   ?

Comment: fd `0` is standard *input*; I suspect your C program's `write` relies on `/proc/PID/fd/0` being bidirectional. See for example [Writing to stdin of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385948/65304) and [Why write() to STDIN worked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822580/why-write-to-stdin-worked)

Comment: ah thanks a lot , you made  me realize  that i mistook  "text appearing on the terminal"  and  "text written to stdout"  . i can get it working now

Comment: 0: stdin, 1: stdout, 2: stderr, 255: stdout